# Error en android studioAccess denied finding property "ro.sf.lcd_density"

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragment

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a buscar el error?. llevo 3 dias buscando una solución y no la he encontrado siempre es el mismo error

Soy un programador junior así que aun me falta aprender, en si el código lo que busca es actualizar 4 datos de un perfil "Foto de portada, foto de perfil, nombre y teléfono.. estos dos últimos ya lo hace pero el problema siempre esta cuando abro el botón con las 4 opciones siempre salen los mismos errores que están aquí debajo en la lista "

Disculpa si mi código tiene muchos comentarios.. lo hago por para no olvidar lo que hacen las funciones

1. E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.sf.lcd_density"
2. E/InputTransport: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class PerfilFragment extends Fragment {


    // firebase
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    // storage
    StorageReference storageReference;
    // ruta donde se guardaran las fotos seelccionadas o tomadas
    String storageRuta = "Users_perfil_portada_imgs/";

    // vista del xlm
    ImageView avatar, portadaTv;
    TextView nombreTv, emailTv, telefonoTv;
    FloatingActionButton editar;

    //progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pd;


    private  static  final  int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private  static  final  int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private  static  final  int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 400;
    private  static  final  int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 300;

    // array para los persmisos   // sacado de un video que ya no encuentro :'v
    String cameraPermiso[];
    String storagePermiso[];

    // URI de imagen seleccionada    --> https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI

    Uri image_uri;

    // para validar si es Foto de perfil o portada
    String perfilOPortada;


    public PerfilFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);

        // inicializamos vairables de firebase

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
        storageReference = getInstance().getReference();// Firebase storage reference



        // inicializamos los arrays de permiso

        cameraPermiso = new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        storagePermiso = new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};



        // inicializamos valores de la vista

        avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        portadaTv = view.findViewById(R.id.portada);
        nombreTv = view.findViewById(R.id.nombreTv);
        emailTv = view.findViewById(R.id.correoTv);
        telefonoTv = view.findViewById(R.id.telefonoTv);
        editar = view.findViewById(R.id.flotable);

        // inicializamos el progrees dialog
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());


        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                // verigica que lleguen los datos necesarios
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String name = "" + ds.child("name").getValue();
                    String email = "" + ds.child("email").getValue();
                    String phone = "" + ds.child("phone").getValue();
                    String image = "" + ds.child("image").getValue();
                    String portada = "" + ds.child("portada").getValue();


                    // envio
                    nombreTv.setText(name);
                    emailTv.setText(email);
                    telefonoTv.setText(phone);
                    try {

                        Picasso.get().load(image).into(avatar);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        // luego de haber instalado el implemento de piccaso
                        // piccaso se encargara de cambiar la imagen base a la imagen del usuario
                        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_imagen_defecto).into(avatar);


                    }

                    try {

                        Picasso.get().load(portada).into(portadaTv);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        // luego de haber instalado el implemento de piccaso
                        // piccaso se encargara de cambiar la imagen base a la imagen del usuario


                    }

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        // boton de editar

        editar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mostrarDialogoEditarPerfil();
            }
        });

        return view;

    }


    private boolean estadoStoragePermiso(){
        // verifica si el permiso de Storage está habilitado o no
        // return si esta habilitado
        //retur si no lo esta

        boolean resultado = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                ==  (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return resultado;
    }

    private void requisitoStoragePermiso(){
        //solicitud de de Storage cuando se ejecute

        requestPermissions(storagePermiso, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }



    private boolean estadoCamaraPermiso(){
        // verifica si el permiso de Storage está habilitado o no
        // return si esta habilitado
        //retur si no lo esta

        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                ==  (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        boolean resultado1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                ==  (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result && resultado1;
    }

    private void requisitoCamaraPermiso(){
        //solicitud de de Storage cuando se ejecute

        requestPermissions(cameraPermiso, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    private void mostrarDialogoEditarPerfil() {

        // opciones que se mostraran
        String opciones [] = {"Cambiar Foto de Perfil","Cambiar Foto de Portada","Cambiar Nombre","Cambiar Telefono"};
        // alert dialogo
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // titulo
        builder.setTitle("Eliga una Accion");
        // envio de seleccion de usuario
        builder.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // logica del clik item

                if (which ==0){
                    // editar perfil

                    pd.setMessage("Actualizando Iamgen de Perfil");
                    perfilOPortada = "image";
                    dialogoDeImagen();

                }else if (which == 1){
                   // editar portada
                    pd.setMessage("Actualizando Iamgen de Portada");
                    perfilOPortada = "portada";
                    dialogoDeImagen();


                }else if (which == 2){
                    // editar nombre
                    pd.setMessage("Actualizando Nuevo Nombre");
                    updNombreTelefonoDialog("name");


                }else if (which == 3){
                    // editar telefono
                    pd.setMessage("Actualizando Nuevo Telefono");
                    updNombreTelefonoDialog("phone");



                }

            }
        });
        // crear y mostrar dialogo
        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void updNombreTelefonoDialog(final String key) {

        /* el parametro key entra los siguientes value
                actualizar  nombre o telefono en la base de datos*/
        // dialogo

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Actualizar "+key);// actualizar nombre o telefono
        // mandar el layout de dialogo
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        //agregar el edit text
        final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
        editText.setHint("Ingrese "+key);  // hint  editar nombre o telefono
        linearLayout.addView(editText);

        builder.setView(linearLayout);

        //botones del dialogo


        // boton de actualizar
        builder.setPositiveButton("Actualizar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // entrada de texto del Edit Text
                String value = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                // validar si el usuario puso o no
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){

                    pd.show();
                    HashMap<String, Object> resultado = new HashMap<>();
                    resultado.put(key, value);

                    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(resultado)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    //actualizar, dissmiss progress

                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Actualizando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });
                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ingrese "+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });

        // boton de cancelar
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        //crear y mostrar el dialogo

        builder.create().show();

    }

    private void dialogoDeImagen() {
    // Mostramos u dualogo donde se pueda ir a galeria o a camara para seleccionar la imagen


        // opciones que se mostraran
        String opciones [] = {"Camara","Galeria"};
        // alert dialogo
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // titulo
        builder.setTitle("Eliga ubicacion de foto");
        // envio de seleccion de usuario
        builder.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // logica del clik item

                if (which == 0) {
                    // camara

                    if (!estadoCamaraPermiso()){
                        requisitoCamaraPermiso();
                    }else{
                        elegirCamara();
                    }

                } else if (which == 1) {
                    // galeria

                    if (!estadoStoragePermiso()){
                         requisitoStoragePermiso();
                    }else{
                        elegirGaleria();
                    }


                }

            }
        });

        }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        // este metodo es se llama cuando el usuario de aceptar o denegar los permisos

        // // // // // // los cassos de permiso // // // // // // //
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:{

                // seleccion de camara, primero se checkea si los permisos estan aceptados o no
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    boolean camaraAceptada = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean storageAceptada = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if(camaraAceptada && storageAceptada){
                        // permiso aceptado
                        elegirCamara();
                    }
                    else{
                    // permiso denegado
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Por favor Habilite os permisos de Camara y Galeria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
            break;
            case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:{

                // seleccion de Galeria, primero se checkea si los permisos estan aceptados o no
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    boolean storageAceptada = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if(storageAceptada){
                        // permiso aceptado
                        elegirGaleria();
                    }
                    else{
                        // permiso denegado
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Porfavor Habilite os permiso de Galeria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }


            }
            break;

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode==IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
                //imagen seleccionada de la galeria, obtenemos el Uri de imagen
                image_uri = data.getData();

                subirFotoPortada(image_uri);

            }
         if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
             //imagen seleccionada de la galeria, obtenemos el Uri de imagen

                subirFotoPortada(image_uri);


         }
        }


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void subirFotoPortada(Uri uri) {

        // ver progreso
        pd.show();

        //ruta y nombre de iamgen seleccionada en el Stored de Firebase Storage

        String rutaArchivoNombre = storageRuta+ ""+ perfilOPortada +"_"+user.getUid();
        StorageReference storageReference2 = storageReference.child(rutaArchivoNombre);
        storageReference2.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        // imagen subida al storage de firebase, ahora tomamos el url y store del usuario en database
                        Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                        Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();

                        // verificar si la imagen no fue subida
                        if (uriTask.isSuccessful()){
                            // imagen subida
                            // agregamos la actualizacion de uri en User's database
                            HashMap<String, Object> resultado = new HashMap<>();
                            resultado.put(perfilOPortada, downloadUri.toString());

                            databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(resultado)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            // agregado el uri con exito a la base de datos del usuario
                                            // dismiss progress bar
                                            pd.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Subiendo Imagen...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            // error al agregar el uri a la base de datos del usuario
                                            // dissmiss progress bar
                                            pd.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error al subir Imagen...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    });

                        }else {
                            //error
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ocurrio un error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

    }

    private void elegirGaleria() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp pic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp Descripcion");
        //
        image_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        // intent del iniciar camara
        Intent  camaraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        camaraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(camaraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
    }

    private void elegirCamara() {

        // buscar en galeria

        Intent galriaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        galriaIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galriaIntent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);

    }
}
```

Comment: Confirma si has estado probando solo en el emulador. saludos!

Comment: uso el emulador de android studio y no ejecuta la app y en mi movil abre la app pero no abre ni galeria ni camara .. ademas tampoco pide el permiso camera y storage .. aunque deberia..

Comment: Hola, no te preocupes, estamos aquí para ayudarte (por lo menos yo). Solo una cosa, las faltas de ortografía y la edición de tus preguntas. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias rafael, lo he corregido.